# Как "выдернуть" значение из ячейки DataGridView?

Tags: c#, datagrid, winforms

Добрый день!Создал Форму1,добавил DataGridView и кинул событие для Формы1:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\CIMV2",
"SELECT * FROM Win32_VideoController");
        foreach (ManagementObject queryObj in searcher.Get())
        {
            dataGridView1.Rows.Add(queryObj["Caption"].ToString(), queryObj["PNPDeviceID"].ToString());
        }
    }
```

Далее для button'a в третьей колонки и кинул событие:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        string url = "http://сайт.ru" + //тут значение из второй колонки// ;
        Process.Start(url);
        Close();
    }
```

В итоге вышла таблица,где выходит Имя и Значение ("Caption" и "PNPDeviceID"),а в третьей колонке по нажатию на button идет переход на сайт.

Вопрос...как выдернуть значение "PNPDeviceID" из второй колонки и подставить в код где написано "//тут значение из второй колонки//"...т.е. чтобы по нажатию на button был переход на сайт с учетом значения во второй колонке "PNPDeviceID"?

Надеюсь понятно поставил вопрос.
Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].Value
```

Comment: То что нужно!Спасибо) Наградить или лайкнуть не получается из-за моей репы.

Comment: Там есть кнопочка принятия ответа слева

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял, в хэндлере кнопки из сендера вытащите номер строки, возьмите значение второй ячейки в этой строке и подставьте куда вам надо.

Comment: Только не sender'а, а аргументов события.

Answer (score 0):

```
CompanyGridView["CompanyID", e.RowIndex].Value;
```

теперь куда бы ты не перемещал столбец, всегда получишь его значение,
CompanyID - имя столбца в CompanyGridView